# Is there any way to optimize c++ string += operator?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, operator-keyword

English is not good, but please understand.

```
string str;
string str_base = "user name = ";
string str_user_input;
string str_system_message;
...

str = str_base + str_user_input + "\n [system message :]" + str_system_message;

cout << str << endl;
```

I'm using the existing code like this, is there a way to optimize string?

I think this code does a lot of useless operations. Is there a way to optimize?

Comment: yes, use `std::ostringstream`

Comment: @Andy The last time I compared the performance of concatenation with stringstream and string::operator+ the later was faster. Every time people didn't believe me they compared themselves and got the same results. Perhaps we did something wrong but nobody was able to show me that stringstream is better.

Comment: If all you want to do is output the concatenated result, then just output the pieces directly: `cout << str_base << str_user_input << "\n [system message :]" << str_system_message << endl;`

Comment: With C++20: `std::format("{}{}\n [system message :]{}", str_base, str_user_input, str_system_message);` otherwise: `fmt::format("{}{}\n [system message :]{}", str_base, str_user_input, str_system_message);`

Comment: Why are you optimizing this specific code?  Does it show up during profiling as a significant processing bottleneck?  The `cout` call is likely to be way more expensive than any of the other lines here.

Comment: Note that the += operator is never used in the code as shown.

Comment: See this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283216/c-string-addition).

Comment: use `std::string_view` instead or a raw char literal: `"\n [system message :]"sv` and you'll save a call to `strlen()` when constructing the `std::string`

Comment: **Please [edit and improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63350848/edit)** by providing some [mre] and real measurements. Explain what will happen to you if a few milliseconds of computer time are lost. Give the context of your software (is it some embedded software driving an autonomous vehicle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says +=, but you're not using += anywhere. You are using only +.

"+" is probably the most efficient way to concatenate strings. There are other ways, but it is unlikely that + is worse.

As John Bollinger said, If all you need to do is output the concatenated result, then output the pieces directly:

```
cout << str_base << str_user_input << "\n [system message :]" << str_system_message << endl;
```

Or with C++20 (as Thomas Sablik says):

```
std::format("{}{}\n [system message :]{}", str_base, str_user_input, str_system_message); otherwise: fmt::format("{}{}\n [system message :]{}", str_base, str_user_input, str_system_message);
```

I would suggest trying to optimize other parts of your code instead (if you need to), since its unlikely you can do better than the language / compiler. forget about optimizing +.

For another perspective, please refer to the answer for this question:

[Efficient string concatenation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611263/efficient-string-concatenation-in-c)

Comment: also [use `'\n'` instead of endl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714)

Comment: @phuclv sometimes you should use `\n`, sometimes you should use `endl`. The link you provided gives some good advice, much more nuanced than your comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I think this code does a lot of useless operations. Is there a way to optimize?

### Don't guess, but do measure by profiling.

Perhaps (on Linux systems at least) with utilities such as [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) or [perf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) or [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), or functions related to [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) such as [clock_gettime(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html). You'll find similar things [for Windows](https://www.kdab.com/software-services/scheduled-training/debugging-profiling-cpp-windows/) and MacOSX and Android at least. Most computers have some hardware similar to [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer). See also [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) for more.

If you use a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, be sure to enable [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). So compile *and link* [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) at least `g++ -Wall -pg -O2 -flto` before using  [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html). Learn also to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger (or another one) to observe the behaviour of your program (its [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics)).

You might be surprised by the optimizations a recent [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) compiler is capable of (in summer 2020), since it will do [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) even when not asked with `inline`. If you happen to understand assembler code, try compiling your C++ code in `foo.cc` using a command line `g++ -O3 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` then look inside the generated `foo.s` file.

Of course, read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website (and [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), a C++ standard) . And read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (and linker).

> I think this code does a lot of useless operations. Is there a way to optimize?

### Leave such micro-optimizations to your C++ compiler.

**Ensure first that your code is correct**, then spend efforts on profiling and optimizations.

When you think of it, **most computers spend their time doing a lot of useless operations**. Read the [blog of the late J.Pitrat](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) and his [*Artificial beings* book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287877683_Artificial_Beings_The_Conscience_of_a_Conscious_Machine).

As a software developer, your role is to balance your development efforts vs the computer time. Today, **computers are most of the time cheaper than software developers**.

If raw performance is very important, spend your time in writing assembler code. If using Linux, read the [Linux Assembly HowTo](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/index.html). Be prepared to be 10x times less productive than in C++....

Consider also doing some [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) and runtime code generation (e.g. with [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), or like [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) does) if performance is important. Read more about [partial evaluation and automatic program generation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/213882771_Partial_Evaluation_and_Automatic_Program_Generation), read also the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353277/841108) says:

> optimization problems look trivial at the first look

### Certainly not trivial. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)!

> I think this code does a lot of useless operations. Is there a way to optimize?

Probably. Consider [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) approaches to optimizations, like in [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) or [Ctuning](https://ctuning.org/) projects. Look (at least for inspiration) inside many open source projects (including [CHARIOT](https://ctuning.org/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/), [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), [SWIG](https://swig.org/)) which *generates* or *analyze* C++ code.

The important question is economical: is it worth your time (e.g. spending *months* of effort, perhaps writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)) to optimize your code by 1%? In some cases, it is worth the effort, in most cases it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically put, there are ways to optimize this:

First, by using += instead of multiple + operations, you will avoid the creation of some temporary objects.

That is, prefer to do:

```
s += s1;
s += s2;
s += s3;
```

instead of:

```
s = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

Second, the call (the += example above) could be preceded by adding up the sizes of the strings and reserving the memory in s.

That said (I did mention it is a "simplistic" answer), here are some other considerations:

- the language designers and compiler developers already spend much much time optimizing string operations, and you are unlikely to significantly optimize your code by micro-optimizations in a function dealing with strings and user input (unless the strings are inordinately large, unless this is code on the critical path and unless you are working in a very constrained system).
- you probably got downvoted because it looks like you are focusing on the wrong problem to solve.
- optimization problems look trivial at the first look, but until you set a performance goal and a way to measure current performance, you are likely to look for optimizations in the wrong place (which it looks like you are doing now).